# stuck 4 minutes at Gigabyte bios screen

Tags: hard-drive, boot, performance, bios, uefi

I have a strange problem when I turn on my PC. I am stuck about 4 minutes at this screen before showing Clover boot loader:

[image]

Since now my PC (Gigabyte Z170X + i7-6700 + GTX970) was OK (NvMe full speed, gaming, working).

If I wait these 4 minutes stuck at BIOS, I can choose Clover boot, then my SIERRA build (Samsung EVO 960 NVMe) takes about 3 minutes to load (FYI one week ago it did it in 40 seconds only. However when SIERRA is fully loaded, everything seems to be normal again, fast and stable...)

The same with Win10 partition (Samsung EVO 850 SSD). After 4 minutes stuck at BIOS, then my Win10 build takes about 4 minutes more to load and then it seems to be pretty fast and stable (Wii emulator, games etc).

I guess something happens with SATA detection? The slowness loading OS is the same with Win or Mac.

I tried following things:

- remove all HDs except only 1 x (Samsung EVO 960 NVMe) (SIERRA only)
- remove all HDs except 1 x (Samsung EVO 850 SSD) (WINDOWS 10 gaming)
- update BIOS to F5
- reset CMOS, removing
  battery and electric wire for 5 or 6 hours, and load default setting
  on BIOS

The same, it takes 4 minutes to show clover boot screen.

Do you have any clue about this problem or why BIOS is taking so long time? I didn't make anything strange, no Win10 updates, no SIERRA updates.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Hackintosh questions are considered off-topic because you're at best in a gray area. Did you try to simply disable the fancy BIOS screen (typically called Logo or similar) to actually see what happens?

Comment: thanks... I have found the problem: an 3.0 USB hub! a very silly thing... Thanks a lot for your recommendation, it helps me a lot
PS. I guess it was not hackintosh issue, but hardware, thanks anyway!